# Error in displaying values

Tags: java

I'm trying to display a function and it end's up having an error , this is the function

```
  public double getInvoiceAmount() 
  {
  return getQuantity() * getPricePerItem(); 
  }
```

and this is where I'm trying to print it with JOptionPane , If I use JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog , it's gonna be displayed without an error , but What I'm looking for is a showmessagedialog , here is the segment of code :

```
    double amounto = getInvoiceAmount();
    String invoice = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invoice Has Been Succesfully       Recorded"+amounto);
```

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` doesn't return anything. So you can't try to save anything from it into `String invoice`. Delete that assignment.

Comment: oh yea ! Stupid I am , thanks .

Comment: What is there to figure out? `double amounto = getInvoiceAmount(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invoice Has Been Succesfully       Recorded"+amounto);`

Or do you want to have a `showInputDialog` with the graphic icon of a message dialog?

Comment: I've Understood , You've solved my problem :) thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function called getInvoiceAmount() is a double type while it has been equaled to a string variable type , so that's when error occurs , it needs the right method for converting double to string  :

```
         double amounto = Double.parseDouble(getInvoiceAmount());
```